# java negative double to the power of a pos/neg double

Tags: java, 3d, double, exponential, negative-number

i am trying to use an exponential to work out the distance the z coordinate would be on screen from the basic z coordinate the object is, as the further away the object is the slower the object moves away and vice versa when the object is coming closer, it speeds up. but the calculation involved in doing so requires a negative double base to double power that may or may not be a negative

```
Math.pow(-1.1, -(z-25))+10.8347
```

if i use numbers between -10 and 20 every 1.5, it gives these answers

```
-10.0 = -17.26773684806433
-8.5 = NaN
-7.0 = 31.948476745352608
-5.5 = NaN
-4.0 = -5.028392971714952
-2.5 = NaN
-1.0 = 22.752876537727232
0.5 = NaN
2.0 = 1.8803975674476092
3.5 = NaN
5.0 = 17.56219994932561
6.5 = NaN
8.0 = 5.780229715007055
9.5 = NaN
11.0 = 14.632198335832413
12.5 = NaN
14.0 = 7.981583293889997
15.5 = NaN
17.0 = 12.978288810000002
18.5 = NaN
20.0 = 9.22419
```

when using desmos, i should be getting a nice slow exponential with an answer to everyone. but here the calculation will only work the input is an even whole number, decimals give NaN and odd numbers seem to be doing their own thing so the only correct numbers here are -10, -4, 2, 8, 14, 20, putting these answers into excel with their answer shows the exponential but i would need this equation to work for pretty much all numbers.

Comment: Did you [read the javadocs for Math.pow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-)?  "If the first argument is finite and less than zero ... [and] if the second argument is finite and not an integer, then the result is NaN."

Comment: then is there a way which i can source my calculation from somewhere else?

Comment: With doubles, no. For instance, `Pow.math(x, 1.5)` is `Pow.math(x, 3./2.)`. That means the square root of x, cubed. If x is negative, its square root is an imaginary number -- and doubles can't express those.

Comment: like using the answers from a site like desmos

Answer (score 2):

A formula that is supposed to give a distance should have a real, not imaginary, result for all applicable inputs.

Raising a negative number to a fractional power has an [imaginary number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number) result. Java double is an approximation to the real numbers. Java Math functions return NaN whenever the result would be imaginary.

Raising a negative number to an even integer power gives a positive result. Raising a negative number to an odd integer power gives a negative result.

You prefer the results for the even integer values of `z`, corresponding to odd integer values of `z-25`. The better behaved formula `-Math.pow(1.1, -(z - 25)) + 10.8347` matches for those inputs, but you need to rethink the theory underlying your formula.

```
-10.0 : -17.26773684806433
-8.5 : -13.524047455696502
-7.0 : -10.279076745352606
-5.5 : -7.466387494888428
-4.0 : -5.028392971714952
-2.5 : -2.91517790750445
-1.0 : -1.0834765377272344
0.5 : 0.5042132175022935
2.0 : 1.8803975674476092
3.5 : 3.0732523797913576
5.0 : 4.107200050674389
6.5 : 5.00340952651492
8.0 : 5.780229715007055
9.5 : 6.453565158914292
11.0 : 7.037201664167585
12.5 : 7.543088549146725
14.0 : 7.981583293889997
15.5 : 8.36166359815682
17.0 : 8.691111189999997
18.5 : 8.976671148126837
20.0 : 9.22419
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out by changing the negatives from

```
Math.pow(-1.1, -(z-25))+10.8347
```

to

```
-(Math.pow(1.1, -(z-25))-10.8347)
```

somehow it let all the answers work

Comment: I agree that the changed formula matches for the values you like, but do you understand why it is right in terms of the theory that led you to your original formula? If not, you may get problems in other cases.